# How to mock java.net.NetworkInterface?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am going to test a method that takes a List of `java.net.NetworkInterface` as argument, and so I should mock the final abstract class or instantiate it.
Any idea about doing these?

The method is something like this:

```
public void handleInterfaces(List<NetworkInterface> interfaces){
    for(NetworkInterface interface : interfaces){
        //get interface mac address
        //get interface name
        //doSomething here;
    }
}
```

Writing a mockito-when for every getter method is kind of ugly, so I think I should write my own version of this POJO class with a constructor. Before doing that, I am wondering is there a better scheme to just do something like this:

```
NetworkInterface mockedInterface = instantiateTheInterface("eth1",192.168.1.1,theMacAddress);
```

I stick with the rule "don't use powermockito ever", so I just implemented a wrapper class and I think its the cleanest way:

```
public class NetworkInterfaceWrapper{
    private NetworkInterface networkInterface;
    public NetworkInterfaceWrapper(NetworkInterface networkInterface){
        this.networkInterface = networkInterface;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return networkInterface.getName();
    }
    ...and so on for all Getters i've used from NetworkInterface
}
```

**Final Solution**
It turns out that there is another annoying Object in NetworkInterface, called InterfaceAddress which i should write another wrapper for that! 
So i am going to use shell commands to retrieve the mac address, net mask and interface name and gateway of host and i don't want to use NetworkInterface ever because with all of these restrictions they are just suggesting "You are not allowed to touch this"!
P.S: I wonder why Oracle guys are obsessed with final abstract, i know that they know more than i do, but in this particular case of NetworkInterface, why final abstract? using a single comprehensive constructor would make the class, immutable too

Comment: maybe you can provide some of your code and explain a little better what you want to test - might be easier to help you then.

Comment: I am not sure if you can Mock a final class but I would consider using an Adapter design pattern.

Comment: @hagrawal you are right, so how to mock it?

Comment: @Enzokie would you please explain more

Comment: I made this comment earlier but since I cannot edit it after 5 minutes so deleted old and here comes edited version: "*should mock the final abstract class or instantiate it*", which class you are talking here? `NetworkInterface` is FINAL class so you cannot extent it.

Comment: @redbeard1970 You want mock a `NetworkInterface` but why and what exactly you want to do it? Probably please edit your question and provide all the details.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment about Oracle guys.

Comment: @redbeard1970 `java.net.NetworkInterface` class is final. This is particularly useful, when creating an immutable class.

Comment: @fabfas one comprehensive constructor could have make it immutable too, and would not cost me this pain that i am not going to use 
NetworkInterface at all, i just edited the post with final solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerMockito to mock java standard library **final** class.

For example;

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ NetworkInterface.class })
public class NetworkInterfaceMocks {

@Test
public void sameClassSuccess() throws Exception {
    final NetworkInterface mockInterface = PowerMockito.mock(NetworkInterface.class);

    when(mockInterface.isUp()).thenReturn(true);
    assertTrue(mockInterface.isUp());
}
```

---

```
@Test
@PrepareForTest(OtherClass.class)
public void differentClassSuccess() throws Exception {
    final NetworkInterface mockInterface = PowerMockito.mock(NetworkInterface.class);

    when(mockInterface.isUp()).thenReturn(true);
    assertTrue(new OtherClass().isUp(mockInterface));
}
```

In my opinion it should be used only in very rare and non-avoidable cases.

Comment: not intrested in PowerMockito, anyway updated the question with my final solution